# How to filter out all grayscale pixels in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project which involves using a thermal video camera to detect objects of a certain temperature.  The output I am receiving from the camera is an image where the pixels of interest (within the specified temperature range) are colored yellow-orange depending on intensity, and all other pixels are grayscale.  I have tried using cv2.inRange() to filter for the colored pixels, but results have been spotty, as the pixel colors I have been provided with in the color lookup tables do not match those actually output by the camera.

I figured then that it would be easiest for me to just filter out all grayscale pixels, as then I will be left with only colored pixels (pixels of interest).  I have tried looping through each pixel of each frame of the video and checking to see if each channel has the same intensity, but this takes far too long to do.  Is there a better way to filter out all grayscale pixels than this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `opencv` specifically but this should be possible: get the saturation as an image, threshold it, apply as a mask.

Comment: How about showing us an image?

Comment: How did you loop through the pixels? Using which method?

Comment: @MarkRansom I am interested whether you think that calculating the saturation (which involves sorting R, G, B to find largest and smallest and then differencing the two) could be faster than calculating (R-G)^2 + (G-B)^2 which involves no `if` statements or branching and stalling?

Comment: @MarkSetchell most libraries have a way of converting an image to HSL or HSV or some other variation directly and at high speed. The thing that really slows you down is trying to do it in native Python.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ah, well spotted! I hadn't noticed the `python` tag and it hadn't occurred to me that anyone would try to do high performance processing in python.

Answer (score 1):

filter out greyscale or filter *in* the allowed colors

Idk if the range of colors or range of greyscale is larger but maybe whitelisting instead of blacklisting is helpful here